# Issue redirect parent of an iframe in Opera

Tags: javascript, iframe, opera

I have an issue when trying to redirect the parent from within an iframe in Opera.

I'm loading an iframe with [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) and when I click on a button in the iframe I want to reload the parent changing its URL arguments. So I've done this, which works in Chrome/FF:

```
window.parent.location.search = $.param(newArgs);
```

But on Opera, it seems to reload the parent with the URL of the iframe instead. I have tried multiple things, adding `return false;` at the end of the click handler, accessing `window.top` too but without success.

The only thing that works is to reconstruct fully the URL like this :

```
window.top.location = window.top.location.pathname + '?' + $.param(newArgs);
```

What have I done wrong or misunderstood about location and iframe?

EDIT: Example in [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DxU8W) thanks to Bergi. On Firefox, this will add "?example=params" at the end of the fiddle url `http://fiddle.jshell.net/DxU8W?example=params` but on Opera this will be added to the iframe url : `http://fiddle.jshell.net/DxU8W/show/?example=params`

Comment: Demonstration: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DxU8W

Comment: I would assume this is a bug. Have you already reported it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug (your report is now tracked internally as CORE-49399 - thanks!). ETA: it's not unlikely that we'll have this working in Opera 14, but I can't tell you when it will be released.

Comment: > Thanks, I've reported it this morning too with the code DSK-382210!

Comment: Yes, that's the bug and thanks for reporting it - it's just morphed into a CORE one for internal reasons ;-)

Comment: Where can I find this bug if I want to follow its resolution? Is there a way or do you need to be an Opera developer to do so ?

Comment: Opera's bug tracker is closed. http://www.quora.com/Opera-Software/Why-issnt-there-any-official-public-buglist-for-Opera